# Determining Subclasses Types with Attribute

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I have the following class hierarchy

```
Promotion   -  abstract
  - Coupon
  - Sales
  - Deals
```

(Coupons, Sales and Deals are all subclasses of Promotion).

and would like to determine the type of the object when exchanging data between the REST APIs (JSON) and the Client (Angular). Users can submit a **Coupon** or a **Deal** or a **Sale**. For instance when a coupon is sent from the client, I want to be able to know that this is coupon so that i can call the correct method.

To solve this problem I have declared a variable and an abstract method in Promotion.

```
protected String promotionType = getPromotionType();
protected abstract String getPromotionType();
```

In the subclasses for instance in **Coupon** I have something like this

```
protected String getPromotionType() {
        return "coupon"
       // OR  return this.getClass().getSimpleName().toLowerCase();
    }
```

This will automatically initialize the **promotionType** variable so that in the Controllers I can check if the object is **Coupon** or **Sales** or **Deal**. Remember that **JSON** send data in String formats so I must I have a way to determine the type of object coming.

In this case I will have a single controller to handle all my CRUD operations. In my controller method I will do something like::

```
@PostMapping public void create(@RequestBody Promotion){

     // And inside here I will check the type of **promotionType**

}
```

Here am using **Promotion** as argument instead of any of the subclasses in the **create()** method.

My question is, is it the best way to solve this?

Or do I have to create a separate Controller for each of the subclass? I am looking for the best way to do it in the real world.

I am using Hibernate for my mappings.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, is it the best way to solve this?

Answers to this question will always be opinion-based, especially, as we don't know about your entire application, not only technically but business-wise, and how the client-code consumes and displays the code.

> Or do i have to create a separate Controller for each of the subclass?

No, not necessarily. If the code is *and would probably stay* simple - sometime you can anticipate this - it doesn't make sense to inflate the code. Having three `Controllers` instead of a single `PromotionController` will very likely increase redundant code. Otherwise, if the subclasseses are rather heterogeneous, three Controllers could be more advisable.

Another thought, you might have a (human) client that manages only the `Deals` and that client has special requirements leading to a bunch of customized rest interfaces only for the `Deal`, you'd probably like to have a separate `Controller`.

> I am looking for the best way to do it in the real world.

There is no best way. Five developers have probably five opinions on how to solve this. And even if one is more reasonable for the time being, it may change on the next day due to or changed new business requirements.

The best way is to discuss this in the team, create a common sense and if unsure, let the lead architect decide which way to go. Imo, your approach seems quite ok. That's my 2 cents.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The application is coupons and Deals site where users will submit coupons, deals or sales of products.